# Scaling Kinect input up ( detected silhuette ) to match a 16:9 resolution

Tags: java, processing, kinect, openni

I'm working on a realtime projection based on a backgorund and foreground video. The foreground video is supposed to be projected on a person dancing in front of the kinect.

Currently, I'm struggling with the scaling of this setup. Obviously the output of the processing sketch needs to be fullscreen. And the videos' resolution is 1280x720.

This is the source code:

```
import processing.video.*;
import SimpleOpenNI.*;

// Member
SimpleOpenNI context;
int[] userMap;
PImage rgbImage;
PImage userImage;
color pixelColor;
Movie foreground;
Movie background;

void setup() {
  size(640, 480);
  //frame.setResizable(true);
  // initialize kinect
  context = new SimpleOpenNI(this);
  context.enableRGB();
  context.enableDepth();
  context.enableUser();
  // initialize user image and videos
  userImage = createImage(width, height, RGB);
  foreground = new Movie(this, "foreground.mp4");
  foreground.loop();
  //foreground.play();
  background = new Movie (this, "background.mp4");
  background.loop();
  //background.play();

  //println("foreground length : " + foreground.pixels.length);
  // background length is 0 on the very first frame
  //println("background length : " + background.pixels.length);
}

void draw() {
  // draw foreground
  image(foreground, 0, 0);

  context.update();
  rgbImage=context.rgbImage();

  userMap=context.userMap();
  for(int y=0;y<context.depthHeight();y++){
    for(int x=0;x<context.depthWidth();x++){
      // use silhuette to cut out foreground movie
      int index=x+y*640;
      if(userMap[index]!=0){
          pixelColor=rgbImage.pixels[index];
        userImage.pixels[index]=color(0,255, 0 , 0);
      }else{
        //userImage.pixels[index] = color(255);
        // the first frame of the second movie is not read on the very first frame !!!
        if(frameCount > 1){
          // -> index out of bounds exception if frameCount == 0
          userImage.pixels[index] = background.pixels[index];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // display the result
  userImage.updatePixels();
  image(userImage,0,0);
}

// read both movies
void movieEvent(Movie m){
  if(m == foreground){
   foreground.read();
  }
  if (m == background){
    background.read();
  }
}
```

What are the most logical or best approaches to scale this up to HD FullScreen? The kinect's ratio is 4:3 which makes it a little uncomfortable.

Comment: just rescale the image to desired resolution?

Comment: This would be the dirty solution, but I'd like to avoid any distortion on the silhuette.

I might could live with that till the Kinect One is available with a real 16:9 ratio in rresolution.

Comment: if you do not wish to change the aspect ration you will need to do isotripic resize and then crop the image to desired size.

Comment: thanks, didn't think about that approach. I'll update this as soon as time is available.